# Thymeleaf Select Dropdown Not Populating

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

In my spring boot app, I am struggling to populate a select dropdown. My page which is to show the select dropdown code is as follows

```
<form th:action="@{/payment}" modelAttribute="homeFormBean" th:object="${homeFormBean}" method="POST">
    <section id="cover" class="min-vh-100">
        <div id="cover-caption">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row text-black">
                    <div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-10 mx-auto text-center form p-4">
                        <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                            <label>Type</label>
                            <select class="form-control" th:field="*{selectedPaymentType}">
                                <option value="">Choose...</option>
                                <option th:each="paymentServiceType : ${paymentServiceTypeList}"
                                        th:value="${paymentServiceType.code}"
                                        th:utext="${paymentServiceType.description}"/>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <label>From Date</label>
                            <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" th:name="fromDate">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <label>To Date</label>
                            <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" th:name="toDate">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group container">
                            <br/>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Go</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</form>
```

The HomeFormBean object has the following properties

```
private List<Lookup> paymentServiceTypeList;
private String selectedPaymentType;
private String fromDate;
private String toDate;
```

When the page is loaded the model attribute is set as follows

```
//this.userPaymentLookupList has the drop down values.
HomeFormBean homeFormBean = new HomeFormBean();
homeFormBean.setPaymentServiceTypeList(this.userPaymentLookupList);
model.addAttribute("homeFormBean", homeFormBean);
```

With all this done, my select option is still not populated with values. What have I goofed up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use:

```
<option th:each="paymentServiceType : ${paymentServiceTypeList}"
                                        th:value="${paymentServiceType.code}"
                                        th:utext="${paymentServiceType.description}"/>
```

Which means that the `paymentServiceTypeList` needs to be an attribute of the model directly.

So either update the controller to use:

```
HomeFormBean homeFormBean = new HomeFormBean();
model.addAttribute("paymentServiceTypeList", this.userPaymentLookupList);
model.addAttribute("homeFormBean", homeFormBean);
```

or update the Thymeleaf template to use:

```
<option th:each="paymentServiceType : *{paymentServiceTypeList}"
                                        th:value="${paymentServiceType.code}"
                                        th:utext="${paymentServiceType.description}"/>
```

My personal preference would be to update the controller and remove the `private List<Lookup> paymentServiceTypeList` field from the `HomeFormBean`.